# Apostrophe/Quotation Not Working

Tags: excel, keyboard, apostrophe, quotations

This is kind of silly, but the answer is eluding me and the issue is driving me a bit bonkers. Every now and then Excel decides to not let me use ' and " properly, forcing me to press another key before it appears. The thing is, the only solution I can ever find to this problem is changing the keyboard layout. For this very reason, I only have US English as a keyboard option and yet Excel still pulls this prank on me. It's also only Excel doing it, I can type totally normally in web browsers as well as Word.

Is it possible I accidentally hit some setting or something? Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Eventually it just sort of goes away, but it might be days before that happens, so I'm thinking there must be a button I'm bumping on accident that is toggling this setting.

Comment: Really? Did you just edit my post for spelling and grammar? The typo I'll give you, but was it necessary for you to edit for style as well?

Comment: Please can you update your question to give a specific example of when this happens. There is a special use for the apostrophe in Excel which may explain the behaviour.

Comment: @8xInfinity the ability for other users to edit your posts is an essential component of SO.  Even if the edit is very small, improving readability will only _help you_ get the answer you want (many users are non-native english speakers but very adept coders, so clear language helps them answer you).  An edit is not a personal slight against you, it is mearly someone helping you get an answer

Comment: Further, this isn't technically a question appropriate for SO, which is focused on coding.  I'm not really sure where a technical problem like this could be asked, so I guess its fine to stay here, but for the future SO is dedicated to finding errors in code

Comment: Had similar problem.  Can't recall exact fix, but, IIRC, it had to do with a setting in `Control Panel` ► `Clock, Language, and Region` ► `Language`

Comment: I agree that this question doesn't seem to fit very well with coding or StackOverflow. I'm having a weird apostrophe problem that I mentioned here: https://superuser.com/questions/122625/apostrophes-and-double-quotes-dont-show-up-until-i-type-the-next-letter#comment1926812_122625